# Making a Multidimensional Array using loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I wanted to have an array like this using a for / foreach loop in PHP because I'm going to pass an array. But it's difficult to make. And how will I display this in HTML?

```
$Food_Order = array(
                    array("Chicken",1,50),
                    array("Beef",2,5),
                    array("Fish",3,10),
                    array("Pork",4,15)
              );
```

Comment: Your quetion is not very clear. If `$Food_Order` is array and you want to fill it, when you iterate through it, use: `$Food_Order[] = array(...)`

Comment: Do you want this result? `[["Chicken",1,50],["Beef",2,5],["Fish",3,10],["Pork",4,15]]`? This is wrong.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. Post your inputs along with expected output

Comment: Your question is unclear though if you are looking a way to print value of multidimensional array element in HTML then use like $Food_Order[0][0]. see http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp more details of multidimensional array

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. You can try the following. I hope it solves your requirement.

```
$Food_Order=array();
for($foodCounter=0; $foodCounter<4; $foodCounter++)
{
     //Assuming that $foodName, $orderQuantity and $foodPrice come from a Data Source
     $Food_Order[$foodCounter]=array($foodName, $orderQuantity, $foodPrice);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($Food_Order);
echo "</pre>";
```